# php function not returning correct file date

Tags: php

Not sure why but I can't get a PHP function to display time a certain file been submitted. ex; about 1 year ago or about 2 sec ago. However in my case its stuck at "about 1 day ago" even if file has been submitted seconds ago.

Here is the function that should get time since submission

```
function time_since($since) {
    $chunks = array(
        array(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 , 'year'),
        array(60 * 60 * 24 * 30 , 'month'),
        array(60 * 60 * 24 * 7, 'week'),
        array(60 * 60 * 24 , 'day'),
        array(60 * 60 , 'hour'),
        array(60 , 'minute'),
        array(1 , 'second')
    );

    for ($i = 0, $j = count($chunks); $i < $j; $i++) {
        $seconds = $chunks[$i][0];
        $name = $chunks[$i][1];
        if (($count = floor($since / $seconds)) != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    $print = ($count == 1) ? '1 '.$name : "$count {$name}s";
    return $print;
}
```

and here is the code which uses above function and injects all of the info into JSON

```
$dh = opendir($dir);
$files = array();
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if ($file != '.' AND $file != '..' ) {
        if (filetype($dir . $file) == 'file') {
            $files[] = array(
                'id' => $domain.$dir.$file."?".Salt($file),
                'name' => $file,
                'size' => filesize($dir . $file). ' bytes',
                'date' => time_since(date("ymd Hi", filemtime($dir . $file))),
                'path' => $domain.$dir.$file,
                'thumb' => $domain.$dir."thumbnails/".$file
                #'thumb' => $dir . 'thumbs/' . $file
            );
        }            
    }
}
closedir($dh);

    $json = json_encode($files);

    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
    echo $callback.'('. $json . ')';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried pass timestamp and not a string for your function:

```
'date' => time_since(time() - filemtime($dir . $file)),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your date to an unix timestamp before doing calculations.

```
            'date' => time_since(date("ymd Hi", filemtime($dir . $file))),
```

should be :

```
            'date' => time_since(strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:00", filemtime($dir . $file)))),
```

Update:

@Arthur Halma just gave the right answer : filemtime returns a timestamp !

```
            'date' => time_since(time() - filemtime($dir . $file)),
```

Should work.